# Disable/Customize comment (re-)formatting in Resharper when using code cleanup

Tags: resharper

Is there a way to define how the comments are "cleaned" using Resharper (6)? I didn't find a solution to this problem.

Before code cleanup:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a comment.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
   ... <not yet cleaned code is here>
}
```

After code cleanup:

```
/// <summary>
///   This is a comment.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
   ... <cleaned code is here>
}
```

Wanted result:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a comment.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
   ... <cleaned code is here>
}
```

Remarks: I don't want to disable the cleanup for a single class etc. I just want to change the indent within the comment which is added accidently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution (using ReSharper 6.1.1000.8.2).

Open up the menu: *ReSharper->Options->Code Editing->Code Cleanup->(Select profile, needs to be a user defined profile)->C#->Disable Reformat embedded XML doc comments*

This seems to be a new checkbox in ReSharper 6.1!?

This solution will not set the indent but disables the comment reformating. Thus you'll have to clean up the comments yourself but they are no longer changed (using the wrong indent) by ReSharper.

I hope, JetBrains will add an option to support setting the indent separately within the next versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. Here it is on the ReSharper bug tracking site: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-275881